# Edit with bootstrap modal and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, popup, bootstrap-modal, edit

I have made bootstrap modal for edit particular data from my data-table.
I am able to open popup and able to fetch my data as well, but as i am doing some changes in modal's text box it is suddenly reflect to data-table also (data-table is in another controller).

I want to reflect it in data-table only if I am clicking **Update** button.
And if I click **cancel** button then the previous value should be there.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="Filterlist in macAddressListResult" class="text-center">
    <td>{{1+$index}}</td>
    <td class="padding-top-8">
         <span class="label" >{{Filterlist.status}}</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>{{Filterlist.macAddress}}</span></td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="openModal(Filterlist)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="Edit">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </button>
        <button  class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Delete">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is Modal HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-header bg-color">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            MacAddress
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-10">:
            <input type="text" ng-model="mac.macAddress" name="macAddress" >
        </div>      
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            status 
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-10">:
            <select type="text" ng-model="mac.status" name="macAddress" >
                <option ng-repeat="p in denyAllow">{{p}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok(mac)"> Save </button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here is angularJS code:

```
app.controller('networkModeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $state, networkModeService,  $modal, $timeout){
    $scope.openModal    = function(mac){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partials/settings/macAddressEdit.html',
            controller:  'macAddressEditCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            scope: $scope,
            resolve: {
                mac: function () { return mac}
            }
        });
    }
});

app.controller('macAddressEditCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $modalInstance, mac, networkModeService, indexService){
    $scope.mac  = mac; 

    // === Get Mac address filter  mode (allow/Deny) list === //
    networkModeService.denyAllow().success(function(result){
        $scope.denyAllow    = result; 
    });

    // === function to  save mac staus  ===//
    $scope.ok    = function(mac) {
        $modalInstance.close();  
    };  

    // === function to cancel  model  === //
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

So, please anyone know me where I am going wrong!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of two-way data binding, which is the core feature of AngularJS.

When you pass the `Filterlist` object to the modal with `scope` set to `$scope`, you are effectively letting the modal communicate with the data in datatable directly, and updating it in real time.

To achieve your requirement, you should [copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) the `Filterlist` object like this in your controller:

`$scope.updateFilterlist = angular.copy($scope.Filterlist);`

And pass it to the modal:

```
<button ng-click="openModal(updateFilterlist)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="Edit">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Or do it directly in the view code:

```
<button ng-click="openModal(angular.copy(Filterlist))" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" title="Edit">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
</button>
```

This will create two different instances of the object in memory so that changes to one in the modal do not reflect on the other in the datatable.

You can then add code to copy the changes made to `updatedFilterlist` to `Filterlist` when 'Update' button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But first option is not possible and second option is not working.