# angular one way binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am using angular 1.3.15. I want to bind data, such a way that, first time variable(`$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping` ) assigned data from `$scope.shipping_address`. Later on even if , variable named `$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping` data modified, it should not haveve any impact on other `$scope.shipping_address`. I am talking about one time binding or one way binding

Answer (score 2):

you should use `angular.copy()` for deep coping

```
$scope.shipping_address = angular.copy($scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping)
```

this way even if `$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping` modify its not gonna bind to the `$scope.shipping_address`

Comment: what is deep coping

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are not looking for **binding** but simply assigning a value of a variable to another. When working with JSON objects (and `$scope` is one such object), making `a = b` is NOT copying the contents of `b` to `a`, but making both `a` and `b` reference the same object. The best way is to perform the assignment as:

```
b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)) ;
```

In your case:

```
$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.shipping_address)) ;
```

One you do this, both variables hold the same information but they can be changed without affecting the other.

Comment: json.parse is doing parsing and json.stringify converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string. How it actually work when it comes for assigning value

Comment: JSON.parse takes a JSON-Compatible string and returns a JSON object. JSON.strigify takes a JSON object and returns a string. So, using this you are making a copy of the object you want to assign to `b` (in my example) and making the assignment without linking the source and the target variables.

Comment: By the way, I prefer this approach because it is independent of other libraries (like Angular).

Answer (score 2):

A similar requirement was asked in this question:
[Edit with bootstrap modal and angulajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609600/edit-with-bootstrap-modal-and-angulajs/38610311#38610311)

Similarly, you can use the AngularJS [copy](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function to replicate your data without any lingering bindings.

```
$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping = angular.copy($scope.shipping_address);
```

Here we are copying the value from `$scope.shipping_address` into the other variable. Now even if you make a change to `$scope.twotap_builtin_cart.sites[sikey].shipping`, this will not be reflected in `$scope.shipping_address` - which is what you want.